# How to Use Delete Triggers to Delete Rows From Same Table?

Tags: android, sqlite

Given the following table.

**MY_TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (COL_1 VARCHAR, COL_2 VARCHAR);
```

I have created the following trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXIST MY_TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE ON MY_TABLE FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COL_2=currentrow.COL_1
```

**MY_TRIGGER** is triggered whenever a row is about to be deleted. What I want is subsequently delete some other rows within the same table where a condition holds true.

I have two questions:

1. How can I access the hypothetical `currentrow` and its columns' values?
2. And will a trigger execute for the trigger-run-delete-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `AFTER TRIGGER` and refer to deleted columns by using `old`:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (COL_1 VARCHAR, COL_2 VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,1), (1,2),(2,1),(2,2);

CREATE TRIGGER  MY_TRIGGER 
AFTER DELETE ON MY_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  DELETE FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE COL_2=old.COL_1;
END

DELETE FROM My_TABLE WHERE col_1 = 1;

SELECT * FROM My_Table;
-- 2 2
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=06b995570e053d8d0690de619206200d)**

More on [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

> Both the WHEN clause and the trigger actions may access elements of
> the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the
> form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the
> name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.
> OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
> which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> INSERT    NEW references are valid
>
> UPDATE    NEW and OLD references are valid
>
> DELETE    OLD references are valid

Comment: Is this to say there is no substitute for old in a `BEFORE` `TRIGGER`? Also you haven't answered my second question.

Comment: And could you share the link to documentation for `old`?

Comment: @Abbas Yes, you could use `BEFORE TRIGGER`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I tried the same in sql developer but it is giving me an error like "This table is mutating, trigger might not notice that."

Comment: @Sandeep This solution is intended for SQLite and based on your message you are using Oracle which is completely different RDBMS

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I found a way to use it in oracle. Basically use an after update trigger and use a delete statement on the same table.